# How to increase the spacing between items in the left sidebar of Nemo file manager?

Tags: themes, filemanager, nemo, css

I want to increase the spacing between the items in the left sidebar of the Nemo file manager. By default the spacing is small, so, for me, the items looks cluttered.

Is there a way to increase that spacing using CSS or any other way?

[image: Nemo sidebar]

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can increase that spacing by adding these two lines of code to the `gtk.css` file:

```css
.nemo-window .sidebar .cell {
padding: 2px; }
```

However, it would be better to put them in a separate css file, especially if you plan to make further changes in the future:

1. Create a folder named `.themes` in your home directory.

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.themes
   ```
2. Let's say you are using the `A-theme` (no pun intended) in `/usr/share/themes`, copy the folder containing that theme to the `.themes` folder just created.

   ```
   cp -r /usr/share/themes/A-theme ~/.themes
   ```
3. Go to the `gtk-3.0` folder in `~/.themes/A-theme`, then create a new folder named `apps`.

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.themes/A-theme/gtk-3.0/apps
   ```
4. Create a file named `nemo.css` in that `apps` folder (using `gedit`):

   ```
   gedit ~/.themes/A-theme/gtk-3.0/apps/nemo.css
   ```

   Put the two lines of code mentioned at the beginning into the file and save it.
5. Go back to the `gtk-3.0` folder, then open the `gtk.css` file (using `gedit`):

   ```
   gedit ~/.themes/A-theme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
   ```

   Add this line to the end of the file and save it:

   ```css
   @import url("apps/nemo.css");
   ```
6. Issue the following commands to reset the theme (or use `gnome-tweak-tool` or `unity-tweak-tool`):

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'A-theme'
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'A-theme'
   ```

**Notes:**

- If there is a folder named `gtk-3.20` in `~/.themes/A-theme`, then you have to repeat step 3 to 6 for that folder.
- You can increase or decrease the `padding` value (in the second line) for more or less spacing. I usually set it to `2px` or `1px`.
- Sometimes the change won't take effect immediately even after resetting the theme. In such cases, resetting your icon theme can fix the problem.

Based on the answers from [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=225928) and [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=272708).